# mixed up html style that i need to separate for my divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am calling some data from a web server and I want them to be shown as individual divs. The problem is that they are not shown separately, but in a big `div`.

HTML:

```
<body>
<ul>
<div class="messages-list">
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

The code for the `messages-list`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
var chatForm = $(".chatForm"),
messageInputField = chatForm.find("#message"),
messagesList = $(".messages-list"),
usernameForm = $(".username-setter"),
usernameInput = usernameForm.find(".username-input");
```

The illuminate code:

```
protected $fillable = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
```

And how I called it:

```
class Messages extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['text' , 'sender'];
}
```

I think the problem is the `messages-list`. Is there a way to get the lines saved there and put each on a separate div?

Comment: please show us the code that's causing it.

Comment: @arcs just did. hopefully that's what you need, to understand.

Comment: thanks, but we need more, mainly the code of the loop that's adding the list entries

Comment: @arcs I just added some more code I think it relatable

Comment: What's the `$fillable` for? And where do you call the web server? `conn` is never used in the JS snippet you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. If your HTML is invalid then jQuery will not be able to work with it correctly. You can start by fixing it:

```
<div class="messages-list">
<ul></ul>
</div>
```

I suggest you read up on HTML element/document structure, for example [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html4/element-structure.html).